# How to get grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name', 'last', 'test_num', 'grade'])


df = df.append({'name': 'name_a', 
                'last':  'last_a',
                'test_num': 1,
                'grade':  90},
              ignore_index=True)

df = df.append({'name': 'name_a', 
                'last':  'last_a',
                'test_num': 2,
                'grade':  100},
              ignore_index=True)


df = df.append({'name': 'name_a', 
                'last':  'last_a',
                'test_num': 3,
                'grade':  95},
              ignore_index=True)


df = df.append({'name': 'name_a', 
                'last':  'last_b',
                'test_num': 1,
                'grade':  50},
              ignore_index=True)

df = df.append({'name': 'name_a', 
                'last':  'last_b',
                'test_num': 2,
                'grade':  55},
              ignore_index=True)


df = df.append({'name': 'name_b', 
                'last':  'last_b',
                'test_num': 1,
                'grade':  90},
              ignore_index=True)

df = df.append({'name': 'name_b', 
                'last':  'last_b',
                'test_num': 2,
                'grade':  100},
              ignore_index=True)




df.head(10)
```

output:

```
    name    last    test_num    grade
0   name_a  last_a  1   90
1   name_a  last_a  2   100
2   name_a  last_a  3   95
3   name_a  last_b  1   50
4   name_a  last_b  2   55
5   name_b  last_b  1   90
6   name_b  last_b  2   100
```

I want to create a new dataframe with the following values:

```
    name    last
0   name_a  last_a
1   name_a  last_b
2   name_b  last_b
```

I have tried to use groupby:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['name', 'last'])['name', 'last']
```

but the return result is `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy`

How can I get the output I want as `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get the result you've asked for:

```py
df2 = df[['name', 'last']].groupby(['name', 'last']).count().reset_index()
```

This gives the following result for df2:

```
     name    last
0  name_a  last_a
1  name_a  last_b
2  name_b  last_b
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth(0)`, `head(1)`, `tail(1)`, `first()` or `last()` to get one row in groupby object

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['name', 'last'])[['name', 'last']].nth(0).reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = df.groupby(['name', 'last'])[['name', 'last']].head(1).reset_index(drop=True)
df4 = df.groupby(['name', 'last'])[['name', 'last']].tail(1).reset_index(drop=True)
df5 = df.groupby(['name', 'last'])[['name', 'last']].first().reset_index(drop=True)
df6 = df.groupby(['name', 'last'])[['name', 'last']].last().reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
print(df2)

     name    last
0  name_a  last_a
1  name_a  last_b
2  name_b  last_b
```

Comment: To match the specified result in the question, you would need to add a call to reset_index(drop=True):  `df2 = df.groupby(['name', 'last'], as_index=False)[['name', 'last']].nth(0).reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: @constantstranger No need `reset_index` because of `as_index=False` when groupby.

Comment: I am simply pointing out that your index values (0, 3, 5) do not match the ones shown in the target result in the question (0, 1, 2). To fix that, you can call reset_index().

Comment: @constantstranger Didn't notice the index, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to `concat` your grouped dataframe to convert it to `DataFrame`

```py
df3 = pd.concat(dict(iter(df2)).values())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['name','last']].drop_duplicates()
```